# Trickle not behaving as expected

Tags: networking, limit

I'm using Ubuntu Trusty 14.04 64 bits.

I've installed `trickle` network shaper from repositories and I performed some tests:

- No limits

I executed this command to test somehow my network download limit:

`wget -c ftp://ftp.cesca.cat/ubuntu/release/trusty/ubuntu-14.04.1-server-amd64.iso`

I obtained an stable download speed of ~9 MB/s without cuts.

- Limit to 200 KB/s

I used this command to limit my download speed to 200 KB/s:

`trickle -d 200 wget -c ftp://ftp.cesca.cat/ubuntu/release/trusty/ubuntu-14.04.1-server-amd64.iso`

I obtained a pretty good precise download speed of ~200 KB/s.

- Limit to 1000 KB/s

I used same command to limit my download speed to 1000 KB/s:

`trickle -d 1000 wget -c ftp://ftp.cesca.cat/ubuntu/release/trusty/ubuntu-14.04.1-server-amd64.iso`

The network speed was ~200 KB/s, very stable, but I was expecting around 1000 KB/s.

- Limit to 100 KB/s

I used same command to limit my download speed to 100 KB/s:

`trickle -d 100 wget -c ftp://ftp.cesca.cat/ubuntu/release/trusty/ubuntu-14.04.1-server-amd64.iso`

The network speed was ~100 KB/s, as expected.

I did some more tests, and it seems that limiting with speeds below 200 KB/s, the results were precise. But trying speeds above 200 KB/s, the program always got limited to 200 KB/s.

**Why are these results produced? How can I limit precisely to higher speeds?**

Comment: 1000 KB/s = 10 Mb/s. What is the maximum bandwidth available to you?

Comment: @roaima 1000 KB/s (one thousand) is 1MB/s, in the SI (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_prefix), the prefix M is 1000 (one thousand) times 1K. anyway I got 200KB/s in both cases.

Comment: I agree with you: 1000KB/s is 1MB/s. It is also 10Mb/s. What is your available bandwidth?

Comment: I used B, Bytes all the time in my post. moreover, 1 MB/s (mega bytes per second)  is **not** 10 Mb/s (megabits per second), it is 8 Mb/s, because 1 Byte are 8 bits. this is not the issue of my post.

Comment: If you don't want to answer my question about your available bandwidth I can't offer any more suggestions. Better luck with someone else.

Comment: @roaima read the entire question, please. in the first attempt to download the ISO I got about 9 MB/s, stable without cuts. it is my estimated maximum download speed. in the further tests, I only got 200 KB/s even when I limit it to 1 MB/s. do you understand the issue now?

Comment: You're implying that you have at least 90Mb/s (or even 72Mb/s) bandwidth available to you? Why not just come out and say so?

Comment: do you understand this sentence `I obtained an stable download speed of ~9 MB/s without cuts.`? it is in my question. if I got 9 MB/s, it is supposed that this is my maximum download speed (approximately), at least between me and this FTP server at this precise moment. and yes, I have this speed, because I have an enterprise connection. please stop doing not related questions, I think my question is clear.